# xargs argument in the middle of command

Tags: bash, xargs, arguments

Why is this command not working?

```
echo 'foo
bar' | xargs -I % -L 1 echo yeah % yeah
```

It produces the following output:

```
yeah % yeah foo
yeah % yeah bar
```

While I expected the following output:

```
yeah foo yeah
yeah bar yeah
```

Comment: @don_crissti Oh boy, how trivial! Thank you very much! I would mark that as answer, if you put it under replies, or you can also mark it as duplicate.

Comment: try this `printf '%s\n' foo bar | xargs -I "{}" echo yeah "{}" yeah` instead ;-)